# userSpaceScaleFactor in pyobjc

Tags: objective-c, pyobjc

I've been playing with pyobjc and seem to be getting this warning for I believe the following code.

warning:

> Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7
>   and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use
>   convertRectToBacking: instead.

Code:

```
def findFile_(self, parent):
    panel = NSOpenPanel.openPanel()
    panel.setCanChooseDirectories_(YES)
    panel.setAllowsMultipleSelection_(NO)
    panel.setTitle_("Please Choose a File")
    panel.setPrompt_("Choose")
    panel.runModal()
```

I am not calling this, is it a pyobjc issue?
How do you fix this?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I found this, http://openradar.appspot.com/12095871. Does that mean it can't be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

PyObjC does not call "userSpaceScaleFactor" without explicitly being asked to do so.

The openradar link you mention indicates that the message is caused by a bug in NSOpenPanel (or rather, NSOpenPanel hasn't been updated to full retina support yet).